# Android:Google Plus profile feed

Tags: google-plus

Using Google Api in Google Plus I am getting the public posts performed by that particular user(Logged in by whom) only as follows::

```
private Person profile = null;
profile = plus.people().get("me").execute();    
Plus.Activities.List list = plus.activities().list(id,"public");
((com.google.api.services.plus.Plus.Activities.List) list).setMaxResults(Long.parseLong("50"));
ActivityFeed feed = ((com.google.api.services.plus.Plus.Activities.List) list).execute();
```

How do I get all the posts performed by the user as well as by the other users(friends) as shown in the Google plus user profile?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Google+ APIs only provide access to public posts by a user. Also, Google+ does not currently offer a method that would allow you to list a specific user's friends.